# Find the domain of f and g

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)= x+\frac{1}{x}$ and $g(x)= \frac{x+1}{x+2}$

(a) Find the domain of f and g

(b) Write $f 。g(x)$ as a rational function $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$

(c) Find the domain of $f 。 g$

(d) Find the range of $g 。f$.

Comment: For a) for$f$, $ x$ can't be zero and for $g$, $x$ can't be equal to $-2$. Open up your school textbook to get the solution for b), for c) domain is wherever the expression you got in b) is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a)f is defined on real line except $x=0$. g is defined for on real line except $x=-2$

b)f compose with g is $f(g(x))= \frac{x+1}{x+2}+\frac{x+2}{x+1}$
you can easily expand this to get rational form

c)the composed function will be defined on real line except for points -1 and -2